# Debian: apt-get doesn't find any package

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I've got the Problem that apt-get doesn't find any package on my new installed Debian 7.3.

First I got the error that I should enter the Installation-CD, then I edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and commented the first line out:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20131215-04:56]/ wheezy contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib
```

Then I did `apt-get update`:

```
root@Bautz:~# apt-get update
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates Release.gpg
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Sources
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates Release
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Sources
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Sources
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
OK   http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/contrib Sources
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/contrib Translation-en
OK   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
```

If I want to install any package now via apt-get, I get:

```
root@Bautz:~# apt-get install bmon
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket bmon kann nicht gefunden werden.
root@Bautz:~# apt-get install htop
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket htop kann nicht gefunden werden.
root@Bautz:~#
```

Is there someone who has any advice?

Comment: Here is the debian [mirror list](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list). Try with another mirror. It's not network problem, you're able to run `apt-get update`. Have you modified the apt configuration?

Comment: Can you translate the errors into English? You'll likely get an answer quicker. And tell Walter White we're waiting for him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding some or all of these to your /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-proposed-updates contrib non-free main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Comment: One question... Where can I find list of ALL Debian sources you listed here? Plus I need to read about them a bit.

Comment: @71GA You can read this book, https://debian-handbook.info/, (it is **free** and **online**), it also has a chapter on how to update your system and the repos you asked about. And much more.